# Insert comma separated values from the join into a specific column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a column called **event_list** in my staging table which is a `varchar` of data type and it looks like:

```
1,2,3,4,5,,...
```

What I need is, to insert the appropriate values from the lookup table into the fact table, for the above ids by using the `JOIN` function.

```
value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,...
```

So what I tried is to do a simple join and get the values from the lookup table and insert into the fact, which doesn't work apparently.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN public.event AS "event"
ON "carnivaldata".event_list = "event".id
```

In the above query i'm trying to do the join based on `event_list` column from the staging and the `id` field from the `event` lookup table. But the result was empty.

Where am I going wrong? Is this the right approach?  Any help could be appreciated.

**EDIT**:

**Sample Metadata**

```
staging_table <--- staging table
event_list <----- column
1,2
23,24
5,6

event_list lookup table <--- lookup table
id  value
1   value1
2   value2
23  value23
24  value24
5   value5
6   value6

expected_fact_table <--- fact table (expected result)
event_list          <--- column
value1, value2
value23, value24
value5, value6
```

**JOIN:**

```
INSERT INTO public.fact_table (event_list)
SELECT "event".value AS event_list
FROM public.staging_table AS "staging_table"
LEFT OUTER JOIN public.event_lookup AS "event"
ON "staging_table".event_list = "event".id
```

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in a single column to begin with.

Comment: (1) Redshift is not Postgres.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results, along with their types.  (3)  You might as well include the complete "simple join".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it was actually a client's requirement, hence we can't make any changes on that. I'm using Redshift, and I thought `postgresql` goes hand in hand with Redshift.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sure, i'll add in the sample metadata in the edits with respective to their types and join as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added the sample data, the expected result and the join query.

Comment: Are you permitted to take this source data and convert it into a separate Redshift table format that can provide better performance?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes, I do have the permission.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have wrote up a comment on your answer, if you do have time please have a look into that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can express the logic as:

```
SELECT el.value AS event_list
FROM public.staging_table st LEFT OUTER JOIN
     public.event_lookup el
     ON ',' || st.event_list || ',' LIKE '%,' || el.id || ',%';
```

I'm not sure if this will have reasonable performance at all.  You really need to change the data structure.  This type of operation is definitely not something that Redshift is well-suited for (actually, Postgres is better, because you can readily unnest the values into different rows).

Comment: I tried the above, but I'm only getting one of those value, not all the comma separated values. select ev.value as elist from public.staging_table cp inner join public.event ev on ',' || cp.event_list || ',' LIKE '%,' || ev.id || ',%' limit 2 am i missing anything here ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://blog.holistics.io/splitting-array-string-into-rows-in-amazon-redshift-or-mysql/), you can use 
`UNNEST( STRING_TO_ARRAY(tags, ',') )` to extract the values and then do necessary join, then using `string_agg(expression, delimiter)` you can concat as mentioned [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-aggregate.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try following dynamic query

```
DECLARE @event_list nvarchar(MAX) = N'SELECT event_list FROM public.staging_table WHERE id = 3'

DECLARE @insert nvarchar(MAX) = N'
INSERT INTO public.fact_table (event_list)
SELECT value FROM public.event_lookup WHERE id in (' + @event_list +')'

EXEC sp_executesql @INSERT
```